# Are case class constructor parameters public val fields by default?

Tags: scala, case-class

With reference to the official Scala Documentation:
[case-classes.html](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/scala-book/case-classes.html)
*"Case class constructor parameters are public val fields by default"*

However, the decompilation of .scala

```
case class A(i: Int)
```

shows the below of Java code

```
private final int i; // private, not public
public int i(){ return i; }
```

Does the statement in case-classes.html mean:
"Case class constructor parameters are **private val** fields by default."
However, an automatically generated getter makes it public.

Comment: What the Scala language calls a "field" isn't the same thing JVM (and Java) calls a "field".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, constructor parameters for `case classes` are public `val`s from a language perspective. However a `val` is immutable, so it must be *implemented* as a private value in the class with a public getter but no setter.

Comment: The implementation of public `val`s as private fields has nothing to do with their immutability. Otherwise they'd just be `public final`. A public `var` is also implemented as a private field. The reason is to allow a) a `var`/`val` to override a `def` and b) to later be changed to a `def` without breaking users' code. E.g. the following works: `trait A { def foo: Int }; class B(val foo: Int) extends A; class C(var foo: Int) extends A; case class D(foo: Int) extends A`. You can e.g. "emulate" a `val` by implementing a no-args method, and a `var` by giving both that and a setter `name_=`.

Comment: The reasons that both public var/val would be implemented as private fields are great.